# Алгоритм перебора значений вложенного массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, веб-программирование, ооп, комбинаторика

Есть массив:

```
var arr = 
[
    ["e..1", //         \/
        [ // этот массив всегда последний (у него всегда одинаковый индекс)
            // тут может быть не менее 1 такого вложения (["строка", другие_значения])
            ["a..1", null], 
            ["a..N", null]
        ] 
    ],
    ["e..2", 
        [
            ["b..1", null],
            ["b..2", null],
            ["b..N", null]
        ]
    ],
    ["e..N", 
        [
            ["это просто строка", другие_значения] 
        ]
    ]
];
```

Надо написать код (функцию, рекурсию, что-нибудь), чтобы вывод получился такой (вывод куда угодно):

```
"a..1" | "b..1" | "это просто строка" // вывод 1
"a..1" | "b..2" | "это просто строка" // вывод 2
"a..1" | "b..N" | "это просто строка" // вывод 3
"a..N" | "b..1" | "это просто строка" // вывод 4
"a..N" | "b..2" | "это просто строка" // вывод 5
"a..N" | "b..N" | "это просто строка" // вывод 6
```

a, b, e - может быть любое количество (вложенных массивов может быть много, все похожи).

Ломаю голову уже который день. Не могу придумать логику к программе.
Сам пишу на JavaScript, но ответ можно на любом языке (в том числе и человеческом).

p.s. гуглить умею, но таких сложных примеров (для меня) не нашел.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел 2 решения, оба рабочие.

Решение 1:

```js
var arr =
[
    ["e..1",
        [
            ["a..1", null], 
            ["a..N", null]
        ] 
    ],
    ["e..2",
        [
            ["b..1", null],
            ["b..2", null],
            ["b..N", null]
        ]
    ],
    ["e..N", 
        [
            ["это просто строка", "другие_значения"] 
        ]
    ]
];

r([], 0);
function r(e, n) {
    let a = arr[n][1];
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        e.push(a[i][0]);
        if (n < arr.length-1) {
            r(e, n+1);
        } else {
            console.log(e.join(' | '));
        }
        e.pop();
    }
}
// автор vk.com/spaceofweb
```

Решение 2:

```js
var arr =
[
    ["e..1",
        [
            ["a..1", null], 
            ["a..N", null]
        ] 
    ],
    ["e..2",
        [
            ["b..1", null],
            ["b..2", null],
            ["b..N", null]
        ]
    ],
    ["e..N", 
        [
            ["это просто строка", "другие_значения"] 
        ]
    ]
];

function _0(arr){
    var A = [], B = [], C = 1;
    for(let a of arr) {
        for(let b of a) {
            if(b instanceof Array){
                A.push(b); C *= b.length; B.push(0);
            }
        }
    }
    for(let c = 0, d, D = A.length - 1, E; c < C; c++){
        E = Array(A.length);
        for(let d = 0; d < A.length; d++) E[d] = A[d][B[d]];
        _1(A, B, D);
        var l = '';
        for (let g = 0; g < E.length; g++) {
            g == E.length - 1 ? l += E[g][0] : l += E[g][0] + (' | ')
        }
        console.log(l);
    }
}
function _1(A, B, D) {
    if(D >= 0){
        if(B[D] < A[D].length - 1){
           B[D]++;
        } else {
           B[D] = 0;
           _1(A, B, D - 1);
        }
    }
}
_0(arr);
// автор vk.com/brudo512
```

Всем спасибо за помощь.